# optimize multiple sed statements

Tags: python, perl, bash, sed, awk

I want to optimize my processing of a file with this structure:

```
2014-01-21 14:26:05.900,2014-01-21 14:26:05.740,    0.000,    192.168.40.2,   192.168.40.26,6    ,  8000, 33311,  172000,    2000,.A..S.,  0
2014-01-21 14:29:23.900,2014-01-21 14:29:23.340,    0.000,   192.168.40.26,    192.168.40.2,6    , 33317,  8000, 3052000,    2000,.A....,  0
2014-01-21 14:30:25.900,2014-01-21 14:30:25.330,    0.000,   192.168.40.26,    192.168.40.2,17   , 36193,   514,  558000,    2000,......,  0
2014-01-21 14:31:04.901,2014-01-21 14:31:04.222,    0.000,  192.168.40.242,    192.168.40.2,17   , 57516,   514,  422000,    2000,......,  0
2014-01-21 14:31:13.900,2014-01-21 14:31:13.143,    0.000,   192.168.40.16,    192.168.40.2,17   , 53313,   514,  540000,    2000,......,  0
```

to a file with this structure:

```
2014-01-21 14:26:05.900,900,0.000,192.168.40.2,192.168.40.26,6,8000,33311,172000,2000,.A..S.,0
2014-01-21 14:29:23.900,900,0.000,192.168.40.26,192.168.40.2,6,33317,8000,3052000,2000,.A....,0
2014-01-21 14:30:25.900,900,0.000,192.168.40.26,192.168.40.2,17,36193,514,558000,2000,......,0
2014-01-21 14:31:04.901,901,0.000,192.168.40.242,192.168.40.2,17,57516,514,422000,2000,......,0
2014-01-21 14:31:13.900,900,0.000,192.168.40.16,192.168.40.2,17,53313,514,540000,2000,......,0
```

Commands to optimize:

```
sed -e 's/,\s\+/,/g' -i /tmp/to_filter
sed -e 's/\s\+,/,/g' -i /tmp/to_filter
while IFS=, read -r f1 f2 f3 f4 f5 f6 f7 f8 f9 f10; do
    echo "$f1,${f1##*.},$f3,$f4,$f5,$f6,$f7,$f8,$f9,$f10"
done < /tmp/to_filter
```

Comment: Trivially, you can combine the first two `sed` operations using two `-e` options to one command.  You should also simply pipe the output of `sed` to the `while` loop, rather than rewriting the file.  Think 'temporary files are a dirty hack'.  Of course they're necessary sometimes, and don't hesitate to use them when necessary.  But don't use them when they're not necessary.  All else apart, you have concurrent-use problems (the file name is fixed, so two people running the script at the same time interfere with each other), and you have clean up problems too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {t=$2=$1; sub(/.*\./,"",$2); gsub(/ /,""); $1=t} 1' file      
2014-01-21 14:26:05.900,900,0.000,192.168.40.2,192.168.40.26,6,8000,33311,172000,2000,.A..S.,0
2014-01-21 14:29:23.900,900,0.000,192.168.40.26,192.168.40.2,6,33317,8000,3052000,2000,.A....,0
2014-01-21 14:30:25.900,900,0.000,192.168.40.26,192.168.40.2,17,36193,514,558000,2000,......,0
2014-01-21 14:31:04.901,901,0.000,192.168.40.242,192.168.40.2,17,57516,514,422000,2000,......,0
2014-01-21 14:31:13.900,900,0.000,192.168.40.16,192.168.40.2,17,53313,514,540000,2000,......,0
```

Comment: This looks great except the second field should contain the value between the . and , in the first field.

Comment: You changed your input file, didn't you? OK, I updated the script to copy $1 into $2 before the sub().

Comment: This one wins the test!  Processing time against 500,000 records
real 0m29.505s
user 0m28.670s
sys 0m0.816s

Answer (score 3):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/^([^,.]*\.([^,]*)),[^,]*/\1,\2/;s/\s*,\s*/,/g' file
```

EDIT:

```
sed -r 's/\.([^,]*),[^,]*/.\1,\1/;s/\s*,\s*/,/g' file
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use a [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) one-liner. It maps over every field to remove leading and trailing spaces, then removes all characters from second fields until last `.`, and then print with all fields joined by a comma:

```
perl -F, -ane '
    @F = map { s/\A\s+//; s/\s+\Z//; $_ } @F; 
    $F[1] =~ s/\A.*\.//; 
    printf qq|%s\n|, join q|,|, @F
' infile
```

It yields:

```
2014-01-21 14:26:05.900,900,0.000,192.168.40.2,192.168.40.26,6,8000,33311,172000,2000,.A..S.,0
2014-01-21 14:29:23.900,900,0.000,192.168.40.26,192.168.40.2,6,33317,8000,3052000,2000,.A....,0
2014-01-21 14:30:25.900,900,0.000,192.168.40.26,192.168.40.2,17,36193,514,558000,2000,......,0
2014-01-21 14:31:04.901,901,0.000,192.168.40.242,192.168.40.2,17,57516,514,422000,2000,......,0
2014-01-21 14:31:13.900,900,0.000,192.168.40.16,192.168.40.2,17,53313,514,540000,2000,......,0
```

Comment: This looks great except the second field should contain the value between the . and , in the first field.

Answer (score 0):

Using awk

```
awk '{t=$1;gsub(/ /,"");split($1,a,".");$1=t;$2=a[2]}1' FS=, OFS=, file
```